# Trapping messages in MFC - Whats the difference?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, message

I was just wondering what (if any) the difference was between the following two message traps in MFC for the function, OnSize(..).

## 1 - Via Message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CClassWnd, CBaseClassWnd)
...
    ON_WM_SIZE()
..
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

## 2 - Via afx_message:

```
afx_msg type OnSize(...);
```

They seem to be used interchangeably, which one should be used or does it depend on other factors?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both parts are necessary to add a message handler to a class. The message map should be declared inside your class, together with declarations for any message handler functions (e.g, `OnSize`).

```
class CClassWnd : public CBaseClassWnd {
    ...
    afx_msg void OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP
};
```

`afx_msg` is just an empty placeholder macro - it doesn't actually do anything, but is always included by convention.

The message map is then defined in the class's .cpp file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CClassWnd, CBaseClassWnd)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

These macros generate a lookup table for the class which allows messages received by the window to be dispatched to the corresponding handler functions. The `ON_WM_SIZE` macro allows the `wParam` and `lParam` message parameters in the `WM_SIZE` message to be decoded into more meaningful values for the message handler function (`nType`, `cx`, and `cy` in this case). MFC provides macros for most window messages (`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_DESTROY`, etc).

You can find more information on how message maps work in MFC [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x0cx6b1.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

afx_msg is just an empty macro, it's basically just there to denote that the method is an MFC message handler for readability purposes. Even with afx_msg there you still need to have an entry in the message map.

Comment: Nice to know that, something I've wondered about for awhile.  Maybe I just have too much time on my hands... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the Windows message are already handled by **MFC**, so in these cases you can get away with adding just the method to your derived class.

For example the **CWnd** class (as do many other MFC classes) already maps a few Windows messages into it's message map (i.e. *ON_WM_DRAWITEM*, *ON_WM_MEASUREITEM*, *ON_WM_ENTERIDLE* etc, etc).

But any other message not already mapped by MFC will need to have both a class method and an entry in the message map for it to work.